# finding the average of an entire column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I am trying to create a table includes the overall average rating and the seller's average rating. I have gotten the seller's rating, but not the overall rating. attached is also a sample of the table; (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RucNb.png)

Here is my code so far

```
select
  rating_for_user_id,
  u.user_firstname,
  u.user_lastname,
  count(r.rating_for_user_id) as number_of_ratings_seller_has, 
  CAST( avg(r.rating_value) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) as avg_seller_rating
from vb_user_ratings r
join vb_users u on u.user_id = r.rating_for_user_id
where rating_astype = 'Seller'
group by u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname, rating_for_user_id
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate about what's "overall rating"?

Comment: How do you want to calculate the overall average rating? If one seller has eight times rating1 and another seller has two times rating 5, would the overall rating be ((8 x 1) + (2 x 5)) / 10 = 1.8 or would it be (((8 x 1) / 8) + (5 x 1) / 5)) / 2 = 3? I.e. is the overall avarage the total rating sum divided by the total rating count or is it the total sellers ratings divided by the numbers of sellers?

Comment: And do you want an additional row with the overall rating? Or a column with every row showing the same overall rating value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select DISTINCT rating_for_user_id,
                u.user_firstname, 
                u.user_lastname,
                count(r.rating_for_user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname, rating_for_user_id ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  as number_of_ratings_seller_has,
                CAST( avg(r.rating_value) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname, rating_for_user_id ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as avg_seller_rating,
                CAST( avg(r.rating_value) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) OVER () as avg_rating
from vb_user_ratings r
join vb_users u 
    on u.user_id= r.rating_for_user_id
where rating_astype= 'Seller'
```

The idea is to use [WINDOW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) functions.